# How to sum columns in list with text fields

Tags: python, sum

Say I've a Python list as below:

```
list =  [ ['text',2,3,4], ['text2',4,5,6] ]
y= map(sum,zip(*list))
print y
```

Gives int /str error.

How would I pop all 'text' in all rows and sum the remaining columns. 
Ans: Im looking for [6, 8, 10]
I noticed that field look like int but are str. 4 vs '4'.

Comment: Is the first column always text and the rest always numbers?  Is this from a speadsheet/CSV file?

Comment: @ Mikel, 1st and 7... If  Ifigure out, I can slice wehre I need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [111]: lst =  [ ['text',2,3,4], ['text2',4,5,6] ]

In [112]: import operator

In [113]: print(map(operator.add,*lst))
['texttext2', 6, 8, 10]
```

---

If you don't know *a priori* which columns contain text, then you could use a try..except block to handle the text:

```
lst =  [ ['text',2,3,4], ['text2',4,5,6] ]
result=[]
for column in zip(*lst):
    try:
        result.append(sum(map(int,column)))
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(result)
# [6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: see edit, Also how would i insure all field are int, for prob like ['text','2','3','4']

Comment: FYI: if I wanted to result to return a cleaned lst like [[2,3,4],[4,5,6]], what would i change? remove sum?

Comment: @user428862: Right. If you remove the `sum`, then `result` would equal `[[2, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6]]`. To convert that to `[[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]`, you could use `zip(*(result))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*list)[1:])
[6, 8, 10]

>>> list =  [ ['text','2','3','4'], ['text2','4','5','6'] ]
>>> map(sum , [map(int,i) for i in zip(*list)[1:]] )
[6, 8, 10]
>>>
```

Comment: need to fixed some fields are text. see comment @ unutbu

Answer (score 1):

```
y = map(lambda x: sum(int(k) for k in x[1:]),
        zip(*list))
```

If you also expect decimals, you can change it to `float()` instead of `int()`

Comment: Oh... your "numbers" are actually strings... that makes things more annoying. Will try to edit in something that will work for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tail(l):
    return l[1:]

map(sum, zip(*map(tail, list))
```

Note: I have been doing too much Haskell lately. ;-)